# Disable halt, poweroff, reboot, shutdown

Tags: gnu

we have a RHEL 5.5 admin server, all the team member from same project can access as root via sudo, from this admin server we login all servers as root. now we need to block/disable such halt, poweroff, reboot, shutdown & init0.
Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

He either is root or he isn't - whilst technically you could limit him, as root, he can always undo whatever you do.. so, kind of pointless and you are best off just telling him not to do it!